# DevExpress TextEdit

Tags: silverlight, devexpress, textedit

I have a Dev Express TextEdit which I use in Silverlight, for some reason I cannot enter data in this Text Edit unless my mouse is over the Text Edit.

That is even though the caret in the Text Edit is flashing, I cannot enter data unless I move the mouse over this control.

I want to enter data as long as the caret in the Text Edit is flashing.

Any ideas what could be wrong or a workaround?

Comment: Please add XAML how you defined the TextEdit. Which version of DevExpress are you using?

Comment: It appears to be version 12.1, It has preperties such as 
AcceptsReturn=True
TextWrapping="Wrap"
I cannot see anything else that could be relevant.
Basically this happens when I go to the highlight some text in the text edit(using the mouse) and choose delete on the keyboard. In the proces of using my mouse to highlight text, it is no longer over the control.
It seems the only way I can resume entering information is to move the mouse over the control

Comment: Its actually allowing some keys when this happens, like more Backspaces, left right etc, its just not entering the alpha-numeric keys for some reasons